# refer all seo back to index.php

Tags: ajax, seo, search-engine

What do I need to change to make it so all search results point back to my index.php? I can't do rewrite rules because I have some pages that are ajaxed to my index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Javascript redirect if you hit a file directly. This was the easiest thing for me to do since I was in a wordpress environment and didn't want to mess with much else.

## However, someone also gave me another great idea which was:

add `?redirect=false` for any page that shouldn't be a redirect. that way you can control the redirects from the query string and can leverage apache rewrites. This is the better way if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do with `robots.txt`, it's just not what it's for.

Rewrite rules should work however: you just need to rewrite to `index.php` everything that is not, as you call it, an "ajaxed page" (ie maybe when the requested page isn't `index.php`? Depends on your setup)

Eg:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: With using that kind of htaccess, when I try to ajax in a page that isn't index.php, won't the server send back the index.php due to the rewrite?

Comment: This rewrite rule says: when a page is requested, if it's not "index.php", rewrite to "index.php". I don't know what you mean with "try to ajax in a page that ins't index.php"

Comment: For example, let's say my index.php pulls in a page via AJAX (a kind of client-side curl). Some Javascript on the index is telling the client's browser to fetch contact.php from the server right? Well when the browser does it's work to grab contact.php the server sends back index.php and then I end up with an endless loop and a big mess. See what I mean?

Comment: Maybe. Probably. Test and revert if needed. Anyway, remember that the answer to your question is: "no, not with robots.txt". So you have to find another way.

Comment: dually noted - question modified as necessary.

Comment: Answer modified accordingly: You can't.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your requirement. You state everything should return the index.php  page then complained that the contact.php page didn't work (because it returned the index.php page).